# Kubernetes NetworkPolicy allow external traffic from and to internet but no Pod-to-Pod traffic

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

How can I define my networkpolicy so that both pods (test-server and test-server2) that are in the same namespace are reachable from outside the cluster but cannot reach each other?

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test-server-7555d49f48-sfzv9        1/1     Running   0          63m
test-server2-55c9cc78d4-knn59       1/1     Running   0          100m
```

```
# test: deny all ingress traffic
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: deny-all-ingress
spec:
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

```
# test: allow ingress traffic for test-server service
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-test-server-ingress
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-server
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - {}

---
# test: allow ingress traffic for test-server2 service
kind: NetworkPolicy
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: allow-test-server2-ingress
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-server2
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  ingress:
  - {}
```

Using this approach both services can be accessed externally, but you can also jump from one service to the other.

Comment: Can you use the except key inside ipBlock like in this example?
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/#networkpolicy-resource

Comment: Do they have to be in the same namespace?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I define my `network policy` so that both pods (test-server and test-server2) that are in the same namespace are reachable from outside the cluster but cannot reach each other?

Your `NetworkPolicy` should be something similar to this one, based upon your settings

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: codewizard-block-policy
  namespace: codewizard
spec:
  # You can also add podSelection to 
  # be more specific.... (up to you)
  podSelector: {}

  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress

  ingress:
  - from:
    # Block all traffic from the same subnet (10.10.10.10)
    # Or change the rule to only block a given IP and not a subnet
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.10.10.10/32
        except:
        - 172.17.0.0/16 
    # Add allow ip from your LoadBalancer IP
  
  # Same thing for out going traffic
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 0.0.0.0/0
        except:
        - 172.17.0.0/16
```

---

- Another solution might be to use `Ingress` with the following annotation:
  `ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "x.x.x.x/xx"`

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whitelist
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/whitelist-source-range: "1.1.1.1/24"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: whitelist.test.net
  http:
    paths:
    - path: /
    backend:
      serviceName: webserver
     servicePort: 80
```

Comment: When I try your networkpolicy,  I always get the error message that the specified ip address range in the except must be a subset of the cidr range. If I interpret it correctly, I first deny everything and then I say explicitly which ip addr range should be possible. The except range can exclude one or more from the allowed cidr range.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming traffic comes in through an Ingress (controller) you can also restrict the `ingress` traffic to the ingress pods like so:

```
  ingress:
  - from:
    # only allow the Ingress controller to reach the pod, this forbids pod-to-pod traffic (only for those that match the policy's podSelector)
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx #(or any other label specific to your ingress controller)
```